# How use Play Framework 2.8 WebSocket with Sink and Source?

Tags: websocket, playframework, playframework-2.0

I think I'd like to use Play's and Akka's `in: Sink` and `out: Source` for WebSocket (rather than creating an actor). I'm so far unable to figure out how to do that though.

How do I send messages to an 'out' Source? How do I close the 'in' and 'out'?  How do I know if the client closed the connection?

I looked at the Nodejs WebSocket docs: https://github.com/websockets/ws#echowebsocketorg-demo:

- There's:  `ws.send('hello client');` — can I use Play's `out` in the same way somehow?
- There's:  `ws.on('message' ...`  — I can use `Sink.foreach()` for this, right
- And `ws.on('close' ...`  — any Sink / Source 'close' event somehow?
- And `ws.close();` — how do I do that with the *in out Sink Source*?

Or should I use something else than an `in: Sink` and `out: Source`?
I'd rather not create an actor (or, I have questions about that too — that'd be a different topic).

***

Here's the example in [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-Akka-streams-directly):

```
// Log events to the console
val in = akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink.foreach[String](println)

// Send a single 'Hello!' message and then leave the socket open
val out = akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.single("Hello!")
  .concat(akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.maybe)
```

But this leaves me wondering how to close the 'in' Sink and 'out' Source
(some time later, not immediately)
and how do I know when the client closes them. And how to send useful messages to 'out': looking at [the Source docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html), I don't find anything I can use to send *different messages later on*, to the 'out'. Maybe the `ask` method? *"Use the ask pattern to send a request-reply message to the target ref actor"* — unclear to me what that means.

Answer (score 1):

The idea in this case is to use a Flow "fromSinkAndSource" (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Flow/fromSinkAndSource.html), which will require you to give a `Sink` (which will consume messages coming from the client (type `In`)) and a `Source` (which will be used to send messages to the client (type `Out`)).

As you said, the sink can use some `foreach` operator as you said (there might be better options but for now I guess it's ok).

For the source, I would suggest you to use a `Source.queue` (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html). Once you have a queue, you can terminate it by calling its `complete` method. Note, however, that you will need to keep track of the reference to the source somewhere, with a reference to what client it is involved with.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Antoine, thanks, this might work. Looking at `Source/queue.html` seems I can get a `QueueOfferResult.QueueClosed` result when sending to the WS client — so in that way I'll find out if the WS connection is closed? That's when _sending to_ the client  ...

Comment: ... I also tried to find a way to get notified when the `in Sink` closes (so there'd be less need to send messages to the `Source.queue` to find out if the connection is still working),  and I see these `object Sink` methods: `Sink.foreach[String](println)` and `Sink.onComplete(_ => println("WS connection gone"))` — however I don't see how I can create a Sink that has both a _foreach_ and an _onComplete_ method?  (so can get notified both when there's an incoming message, and when the WS `in Sink` has closed because WS connection closed). Are there ways to combine _foreach_ with _onComplete_?

Comment: Would I call `queue.toMat(...).run()`? Or will Play do that for me? Seems until someone has called `.toMat(...).run()`,  there's no `.offer()`  method — one hasn't gotten a `SourceQueueWithComplete` yet

Comment: .. found sth like 5 - 10 other people having the same question, and eventually by chance I stunbled upon:  `Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(inSink,  outSource)((_, outboundMat) => {
        outboundMat.offer(JsString("kittens"))`  in this sample project: https://github.com/JannikArndt/simple-akka-websocket-server-push/blob/master/src/main/scala/WebSocket.scala, that should work I think.

Comment: B.t.w. seems there's a `Flow.fromSinkAndSource(inSink, outSource).watchTermination` method for finding out when the WS closes.